# Linear Varieties as a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, not necessarily algebraically closed.

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $X$ a $G$-variety. If $X$ is also a vector space and $G$ acts on $X$ as elements of $GL(X)$, then $X$ is said to be a linear $G$ variety.

Now, if we have a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ on which $G$ acts, we can identify $V$ with $k^n$ and obtain a linear $G$ variety.

**Starting with a vector space $V$, what's the correct abstraction of a linear $G$-variety from the point of view of schemes?** From the scheme theoretic point of view, $V$ is no longer in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ because of the extra points.

The only thing I could come up with was $X= \operatorname{Spec} (\operatorname{Sym}(V^*))$, since the $k$-points of this scheme correspond to elements of $V$ according to this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96760/schemes-associated-to-vector-spaces). An action of $G$ as a constant group scheme on $X$ would then induce an action of $k$-rational points $G(k)$ on $X(k)=V$ in the usual way (I think). But I would also like some of the properties that would come from $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ like unirationality of $Y$ if $f:\mathbb{A}^n_k\rightarrow Y$ was a dominant map.

Comment: Did you try to compute what $X$ is? I think you'll find you have exactly what you need. (Also, a formatting tip: using `\operatorname` makes things work better - I've made the upgrade to your post this time.)

Comment: Oh thanks! This gives an affine space? I am going to work out the details then.